# Replace path to function or object with Rubberduck

Tags: excel, vba, rubberduck

I've come across a couple of scenarios where I'd like a robust method to change the path (`blah.blah.blah.myObject`) to an object or routine, and I wonder if this is possible with  *Rubberduck*

First scenario: I have a lot of calls to some routine `Bar()` in my code. I've decided to make that function a member of a class or addin `Foo`. So I'd like to replace all calls to `Bar` with `Foo.Bar()`. i.e.

```
Sub TestCode()
    Bar
End Sub
```

becomes

```
Sub TestCode()
    Foo.Bar
End Sub
```

for some publicly declared `Foo` object

---

In another situation, I have the following types declared in a class:

```
Private Type TSubList
    Member1 As Long
    Member2 As String
End Type

Private Type TList
    Member3 As TSubList
    Member4 As Double
End Type

Private this As TList
```

And the call sites look like this:

```
Private Sub TestCode()
    Debug.Print this.Member4, this.Member3.Member1 'dot through 2 levels
End Sub
```

I want to condense the type into a single type like this

```
Private Type TList
    Member1 As Long
    Member2 As String
    Member4 As Double
End Type

Private this As TList
```

Meaning my call site becomes

```
Private Sub TestCode()
    Debug.Print this.Member4, this.Member1 'replace with single level
End Sub
```

---

Does Rubberduck have a more robust way of adding or removing elements of a path to a function/variable than a simple find & replace?

Comment: That would be something like a "move member" refactoring; not implemented as of yet... but I like the idea!

Comment: Great ideas! I've added new issues for the two requests that I could see: https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/4194 and https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/4195